Recovering hyperbolic trigonometry from SL(2,R)
I just read this cool blog post by Tao and one of its comments mentioned that it is possible to recover laws of hyperbolic trigonometry from SL(2,R). I admit that the contents of the blog post is way beyond my mathematical ability (I never took any group theory or abstract algebra course in my life) but I am curious how it is done.
Also, I know it is not relevant to this question but I wonder from what group, one can derive traditional Euclidean trigonometry.

Presumably, $SE(2)$.

All in all, if you never took an abstract algebra, you are simply not ready for any answer to this question.

The prerequisites for a complete answer to this question include (Lie) group theory and Reimannian geometry, perhaps expected of an early-stage graduate student. Nevertheless I think we can give an incomplete answer by gesturing at a theorem from elementary group theory, namely the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Theorem (orbit stabilizer) Let $G$ be a group acting on a space $X$ such that for every $x,y \in X$, there is a $g \in G$ so that $g\cdot x = y$ (this condition is called transitivity). Choose a basepoint $x_0 \in X$ and set $H = \text{Stab}(x_0) = \{g \in G \mid g\cdot x_0 = x_0\}$. Then the coset space $G/H$ is in bijection with $X$.

The reason $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is related to $\mathbb{H}^2$ is that it satisfies the hypotheses of the above theorem, namely that it acts transitively on $\mathbb{H}^2$. We can therefore place $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/H$ (a group-theoretic object) in bijection with $\mathbb{H}^2$ (a geometric object).
The coset space $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/H$ does not immediately recover the geometry of $\mathbb{H}^2$ (the theorem as stated only gives a bijection), but this can be done some additional work. This involves the compactness of point stabilizers and uses an averaging argument to construct a left-invariant Riemannian metric on $G/H$.

No, this way you can only recover the topology, not geometry (let alone, trigonometry). Geometry takes more work.

On the other hand you could recover the geometry if you noticed that $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ acts transitively on the orthonormal frame bundle of $\mathbb H^2$.

@Moishe Kohan, continuing with my last paragraph, we proceed as follows. The fact Lee Mosher noted above implies that the metric has constant curvature. You check that it is not Euclidean space, (hence negative curvature) and rescale the metric to have curvature $-1$. This metric on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/H$ is then isometric to $\mathbb{H}^2$. Perhaps it is fair to say that this procedure only recovers the geometry up to re-scaling the metric.

Yes, this is of course true, but you did not even get started. The challenge is to convert algebra into geometry (see Tao's blog). For instance, what does area mean in terms of cosets and why would Gauss-Bonnet formula hold (without relying upon theorems in differential geometry). Tao outlines how these things are done in the setting of spherical geometry.

As you noted in your comment to the main post, the OP does not have the prerequisites to understand the full answer. In the first paragraph, I say "...nevertheless I think we can give an incomplete answer". I stand by that. The answer is incomple, but hopefully helpful.
